# How to disable rounded images in android studio

Tags: android, image, rounding

I bought a template for android app which has listview and another file with rounded images in and i want to disable it

here is the roundimage.java file

```
    package com.TEST.TEST;



import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;


public class RoundImage extends Drawable {
    private final Bitmap mBitmap;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final RectF mRectF;
    private final int mBitmapWidth;
    private final int mBitmapHeight;
public RoundImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
        mRectF = new RectF();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        final BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        mPaint.setShader(shader);

        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawOval(mRectF, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mRectF.set(bounds);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        if (mPaint.getAlpha() != alpha) {
            mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
            invalidateSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mBitmapWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mBitmapHeight;
    }

    public void setAntiAlias(boolean aa) {
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(aa);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) {
        mPaint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setDither(boolean dither) {
        mPaint.setDither(dither);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return mBitmap;
    }

}
```

and this is a part from the file which i want to disable rounding from

```
if (isExist != false){
        Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        roundedImage = new RoundImage(theImage);
        imgIcon.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);

    }
    else {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.author);
        roundedImage = new RoundImage(bm);
        imgIcon.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);

    }
```

how can i disable rounding for images or control its corners to change it into zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a rectangular image you can edit

```
canvas.drawOval(mRectF, mPaint);
```

to

```
canvas.drawRect(mRectF, mPaint);
```

Comment: Yes this is practically working. But maybe there is no need to use class 'RoundImage'.

Answer (score 0):

Please test this code instead of yours:

```
if (isExist != false){
        roundedImage  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        imgIcon.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
    }
    else {
        roundedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.author);
        imgIcon.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
    }
```

In this code we omit the line which uses RoundImage class.

Comment: i got an error (Required: com.TEST.TEST.RoundImage   Found:android.graphics.Bitamp)